Tron rejects usdt transfer due to bandwidth insufficient but there is enough
I try to send usdt trc20 token which costs 345 of bandwidth. I have about 270 free and also delegated a stacked bandwidth and have this in total 346
    array (
  'freeNetUsed' => 331,
  'freeNetLimit' => 600,
  'NetLimit' => 77,
  'TotalNetLimit' => 43200000000,
  'TotalNetWeight' => 12327067068,
  'EnergyLimit' => 64999,
  'TotalEnergyLimit' => 180000000000,
  'TotalEnergyWeight' => 2439309958,
)

when I try to transfer, I get this error
Account resource insufficient error.

why I can't use free limit ?

I have figured what is the problem. It is appear free and net bandwidth aren't mixing. So you must have either enough free bandwidth or net bandwidth. I suppose tron developers should highlight somehow how much free and net bandwidth available and not show a total amount what is confusing.

You cannot pay for the transfer with what was staked & delegated on Tron.
This is as if you wanted to pay for gas on Ethereum with what was staked in Ethereum staking.
That's exactly the reason you're getting this error.
Hope this helps, please let me know!

sorry I do not understand. I already paid with delegated bandwidth and work well if free bandwidth greater 255. If lower it fail
